# Trying to pull data into an array from firebase to be used in a section list

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am working on a workout log app using react native to use info that is entered into firebase and display it. Right now I am trying to display the top weight and reps of the sets with the top 3 weights for the day.  The issue I am having is that I don't know how to add the 3 documents I want to pull into an array then call that array using a use effect to then call certain aspects of those documents. The data from the firebase documents are going to be put in a section list with one list being reps and the other being weight. I tried a solution (as seen below) and I was getting the error

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'items.length')

This error is located at:
    in VirtualizedSectionList (created by SectionList)
    in SectionList (created by ExerciseGrid)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by ExerciseGrid)
```

To query the 3 documents I created this

```
import { collection, getDocs, orderBy, query, where, limit } from "firebase/firestore";
import db from "../firebase/firestore"


const getInfoData = async ({exercise, date}) => {
  const colRef = collection(db, "UsersData");
  const q = query(colRef,where("Exercise.Exercise","==",exercise), where("date.date", "==", date),orderBy("Weight"), limit(3));  
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)
  
    return (
      querySnapshot
);
  
  
}
export default getInfoData;
```

The main document where I am trying to edit and create the array is in this file

```
const ExerciseGrid = ({exercise}) => {
    //shows the sets
    let tempDate = new Date();
    let day = tempDate.getDate();
    let month = tempDate.getMonth() + 1;
    let year = tempDate.getFullYear();
    
    
    let currentDate = `${month}-${day}-${year}`;
    const baseDate = currentDate;
    console.log();
    const[date, setDate] = useState(currentDate);
    const DATA=[
      {
        id:"1",
        Reps:0,
        Weight: 0,
      },
      {
        id:"2",
        Reps:0,
        Weight: 0,
      },
      {
        id:"3",
        Reps:0,
        Weight: 0,

      },
    ];  
    console.log(date + "check"); //Breaks after this point
    const [windowLength,setWindowLength] = useState(Dimensions.get('window'));
    const [weight,setWeight] = useState();
    const [reps,setReps] = useState();
    const [infoData, setInfoData] = useState(DATA);
    const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
        useEffect(()=>{
            const load = async () => {
                const snapshot = await getInfoData(exercise, date);
                snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                  setWeight(doc.data().Weight.Weight);
                  setReps(doc.data().Reps.Reps);
                  setInfoData(
                    infoData.map((dataInfo) =>
                        dataInfo.id === count
                        ? {
                          ...dataInfo,
                          Reps: [...dataInfo.Reps, reps],
                          Weight: [...dataInfo.Weight, weight],
                      }
                    : { ...dataInfo }
                    )
                  );
                  setCount(count+1);
                });
              };
            load();
    },[])
```

The error described in the problem happens just after the console.log in the file

The section

```
                   infoData.map((dataInfo) =>
                        dataInfo.id === count
                        ? {
                          ...dataInfo,
                          Reps: [...dataInfo.Reps, reps],
                          Weight: [...dataInfo.Weight, weight],
                      }
                    : { ...dataInfo }
```

was added in an attempt to edit the already existing contents of the array. This solution is from online, but I don't believe it worked.

I am expecting the contents of the array to be changed with information from each document where ID: 1 has the greatest weight and how many reps of that weight is completed.

If there was an easier way to make an array with the data or a way to fix the code so I can correctly change the contents of the array, please let me know.

Thanks.